# getting my lambda to output a filtered list containing only values that match the current month

Tags: java, sql

So my school needs us to have a lambda expression for an assignment so i decided that lambda'ing a filtered list may be easier the problem is that my code below keeps giving me the next 30 days no matter what i do and below is just an example of what i am trying but i need a way to see if its possible to get this code:

```
        ObservableList<Appointments> appts = AppointmentsDAO.getAppts();
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        LocalDateTime month = now.plusMonths(1);

        
        FilteredList<Appointments> filter = new FilteredList<>(appts);
        filter.setPredicate(row -> {
            LocalDateTime start = (row.getStartTime().toLocalDateTime());
            return start.isAfter(now) && start.isBefore(month);
        });

        appointmentsTableView.setItems(filter);
```

to output the same as the sql statement i was using before which is :

```
SELECT *
from appointments AS a
  INNER JOIN contacts AS c ON a.Contact_ID=c.Contact_ID
WHERE MONTH(start) = MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(start) = YEAR(NOW());
```

the sql statement gives me a filtered db list of all matching month-year info but how do i translate the same statement for java? im thinking maybe i cant but figured it was worth a try. Also the lit row im filtering is set to a timestamp throughout my program but casting timestamp to localDateTime hasnt been a problem thus far though could be relevant here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lambda looks good.  I think your problem is the date logic.  You are asking filtering for rows between the current datetime and the same day next month.  You want to filter for rows between the beginning of the current month and the end of the current month.  So, with the caveat that this code isn't tested, something like this:

```
ObservableList<Appointments> appts = AppointmentsDAO.getAppts();
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime startOfMonth = now.with(firstDayOfMonth());
LocalDateTime endOfMonth = now.with(lastDayOfMonth());

FilteredList<Appointments> filter = new FilteredList<>(appts);
filter.setPredicate(row -> {
    LocalDateTime start = (row.getStartTime().toLocalDateTime());
    // This next line fails for records falling exactly on the start/end of month...
    // return start.isAfter(startOfMonth) && start.isBefore(endOfMonth);
    // ... this version should do better in that regard
    if ( startOfMonth.isAfter(start) || endOfMonth.isBefore(start) ) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
});



appointmentsTableView.setItems(filter);
```

Comment: amazing! ive been stuck on that all morning! now to do the same with weeks :) sometimes it just takes another set of eyes with a whole lot more experience! Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad to help.  Please upvote and accept the answer if you're satisfied with it.  It rewards me and gets your question off the "unanswered questions" list.